# Recently Viewed Items

Tags: magento-1.8, products, frontend

Is there a way that a user can remove / clear their recently viewed items?  I can see the data is stored in the "report_viewed_product_index" table however not sure if there is a native function to remove records per customer

Comment: There isn't. You will have to write this yourself

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the "frontend" cookie works. That also ends the session though, so the user has to login again.